# Desktop envivornment switching from unity to gnome resulted in blank background with side panel

Tags: 14.04, gnome, desktop-environments

I tried to switch from unity desktop envivornment to gnome using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

And the result is a blank background and side panel as shown in the image

How do I remove this panel?

Answer (score 0):

I think the image failed to come through...

Try this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

as suggested in this tutorial:
http://www.howtogeek.com/189912/how-to-install-the-gnome-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-14.04/